# Express js array form field converting into String field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

In express js I want to post array form field but it converted to string.

**Example : HTML Form**

```
<form>
  <input name="mobile" value="99999999999" />
  <input name="name[]" value="apple" />
  <input name="name[]" value="mango" />
</form>
```

**Server Side**

I got

```
{
     mobile: "99999999999",
    'name[0]': "apple",
    'name[1]': "mango"
}
```

I want key name without single quote. This happen only for array fields only

```
{
    mobile: "99999999999",
    name[0]: "apple",
    name[1]: "mango"
}
```

Anyone can guide me how I can resolve it. I tried so much but not getting success.

Comment: Why do you want it with no quotes?

Comment: Because when I use `request.body.name` I can not get name value

Comment: But isn’t name[0] an invalid property name in JavaScript and therefore it must be quoted?

Comment: And you can get it with request.body[‘name[0]’] even if it is quotes?

Comment: @ChrisCousins But name is dynamic so I can't know howmany length of name field?

Comment: Just iterate over the object properties for any beginning with “name” and then you can parse those. Removing the quotes won’t help and also will mean the keys are invalid.

Comment: @ChrisCousins can you just post code how can I iterate name field please.

Comment: Try it yourself - we’re not here to code for you. If you run into problems then post what issues/errors you get.

Comment: @ChrisCousins I do not want whole code from your side I want only hint how to iterate like `request.body.name.forEach(function(name,key){})` but it does not work.

Comment: It sounds like you really want it to be like `{mobile: "99999999", name: ["apple", "mango"]}`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, exactly. You got my point what I want?

Comment: I don't know Express, but I think the answer says that you should get what you want if you use `extended: true`

Comment: @Barmar I already used `extended: true` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

For bodyParser.urlencoded, if you set the extended option to true, attribute names of the format property[nestedProperty] will be interpreted by the bodyParser middleware as:

```
{ property: nestedPropert: $value }
```

Just be sure to initialize the middleware like so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });
```

With above changes you should be able to get object on form submit

Comment: I used `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` in my code. Is it correct ?

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); you should add this in app.js

Comment: The problem is in this line by the default in the app.js file: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));. (I guess) by the default Express uses extended: false and must be true to work.  with the changes in the  Server configuration you should be able to solve your problem

Comment: I written in my code same as you post like `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));`

Comment: parser the data again on server side var dataReceived = JSON.parse(req.body);

Comment: I already try this but got this error **SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)**

Comment: All form fields are not array field thats why I got error.

Comment: @Sadikhasan POST data is not JSON, it's URL-encoded. So you shouldn't use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Barmar I used `var dataReceived = JSON.parse(req.body)` as mentioned by @Blackfish.  then what should I use?

Comment: I don't use Express, but I think it should parse the body automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, Here is a workaround to achieve the desired result:

We will get the keys from the object and check which key is one of the keys which are array.

> This not the recommended approach but a workaround. This might not be readable and you might not want to use it on Production.

```js
var obj = {
  mobile: "1234",
  "name[0]": "one",
  "name[1]": "two",
  "name[2]": "three",
  "teezNameArr[0]": "xx0",
  "teezNameArr[1]": "xx1",
  "par[0]": "par-one",
  "par[1]": "par-something"
};

var arrayFields = ["name", "teezNameArr", "par"];
var regexString = `^(${arrayFields.join("|")})\\[\\d+\\]`;

var regex = new RegExp(regexString);

var newObj = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter(aKey => regex.test(aKey))
  .reduce((combinedObj, aKey) => {
    var keyName = aKey.match(regex)[1];
    if (!combinedObj[keyName]) {
      combinedObj[keyName] = [];
    }
    combinedObj[keyName].push(obj[aKey]);
    return combinedObj;
  }, {});

newObj.mobile = obj.mobile;

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Here example I given for only `name` field but in my code this type of multiple fields so code is lengthy and not redable.

Comment: I can post more readable and compact code if you can tell me all the fields

Comment: name,teezNameArr,par,hcp,hole_latitude,hole_longitude this all my array fields. Also there are more fields but that contains only string

Comment: Thanks for given your valuable task. But this is not proper way to do this.

Comment: I know! I had already mentioned that in the quotes :) It is just to let you know that if  nothing works, there is this way